# Unify records in one row

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have 2 tables in my DB

**Table1** has

```
sales_ID
date
calls_volume
```

**Table 2** has

```
sales_ID
date
sales_volume
skills_volume (the skills where the sales was logged in)
```

What makes things harder, is that in **Table 1**, there's one record per sales and date (in other words, every sales has 1 record in every day).

However **table2** has one record per sales, date and skills.

When I join the two tables in a query (date and sales_id) I get the calls volume multiplied by skills volume).

can any one help me on that?

Comment: Where's your query - some sample data and the results you have - and the results you want? Also please identify the correct tag - is it sqlite or mysql

Comment: It's extremely unclear what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Thank you everyone. To give you an idea about the app, it's connected through a jdbc to sqlite database. The user is supposed to add in Java gui frames appointments, new customers, product etc.... these datas are stored in separate tables in the database. The customer who will be using this would like to access to the app remotely. My understanding that if he has the Jar file and have access to the DB. The problem will be solved. And my question: where can i host the databse.